# How do we increase the size of a pdf file in salesforce while generating in pdf format?

Tags: unit-test

[image]

find below screen shot , i created 22 fields ,only its showing 16 fields are missing please let me know if any suggestion in this scenario ?

Comment: Can you please add extra information? how did you create the pdf, what does your page/controller look like.

Comment: You can't (AFAIK) make the PDF page bigger and most people's printers will only print letter/A4 size anyway. Are you looking to make the output smaller so it fits on a portrait layout page? Do you want to change the output to landscape?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE user12854. Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Without providing code from your existing page, its nearly impossible for anyone to provide you with concrete advice on how to solve your problem. We'd simply be guessing on what the problem is with your code. It could be a matter of using unsupported VF components per [Best Practices for Rendering PDFs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm) or a variety of other things.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the definition of your @page directive e.g.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" renderAs="pdf" >

    <head>  
    <style>
@page
{
    size: A3 landscape;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    CONTENT HERE

</body>

</apex:page>
```

You'll need to put your content in and add controller and extension parameter to the apex:page tag.